# how to print std::map value in gdb

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb

I have a std::map< std::string, std::string> cont;

I want to see cont[ "some_key" ] in gdb. When I'm trying

p cont[ "some_ket" ]

I'm getting this message: One of the arguments you tried to pass to operator[] could not be converted to what the function wants.

I'm using GNU gdb Red Hat Linux (6.3.0.0-1.162.el4rh). Thanks

Comment: Pity. gdb7.0 can directly print it: http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport

Comment: This is the right answer.  The feature already exists, you're just using an older distribution that hasn't integrated it.  Consider using a recent Fedora, or build the tools (it might just be gdb, though it's possible you'll need g++ and binutils too)  yourself from source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latest gdb has python support baked in so one could easily write a function to print out the contents of any stl structure.  However you'd have to learn the API and write the script.  Luckily gcc 4.5 will ship with the needed python scripts to get gdb to intelligently handle stl data structures.

EDIT: you don't have to wait for GCC 4.5 (which by the way has already been released), you can just [grab the code from SVN](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport).

Answer (score 6):

You can write your own dump functions and call them:

```
(gdb) call dump(m)
```

see this thread:
http://www.mail-archive.com/help-gplusplus@gnu.org/msg02109.html

I'm curious about the GDB helper macros.

Comment: The [next message on that thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/help-gplusplus@gnu.org/msg02189.html) shows a GDB macro that works very well. The subsequent message contains some small improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Gdb doesn't understand C++ operator overloading.

Comment: As I understand there aren't any way to see key-value during debug process?

Comment: Not easily. std::map is a complex data structure. You can follow the (implementation-specific) private members and see what's going on, but it's quite a chore. @Eddy's answer may help, but I haven't played with that stuff at all.